# How to scale out a chat application with SignalR

Tags: .net, signalr, chat, message-bus

How would you scale out a chat application (say something like WhatsApp or Telegram) which is using `SignalR`? Is it even possible or `SignalR` isn't a solution for this kind of applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale up SignalR using redis:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis

This also work on .net Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-2.1